# Prove that limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $n^{-k}$ is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Not sure at all how to start with this one. I understand the basic notion behind it i.e. a fraction with a growing denominator gets smaller but cannot seem to phrase this is a rigorous analytic way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are interested in the case where $k \geq 1$ is an integer. If so, note that $1/n^{k} \leq 1/n$ for all $n$. Given any $\delta > 0$, we have $1/n < \delta$ if and only if $n > 1/\delta$; so for all $n \geq \lfloor 1/\delta \rfloor +1$ we have $1/n^{k} \leq 1/n < \delta$. So $1/n^{k} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.